# How can I line up my sliders horizontally without using absolute positioning? CSS troubles

Tags: html, css

I've run into a problem which is interrupting my ability to continue. I've got a simple full-width carousel/slider under my navbar, but because it's using absolute positioning it's messing up the flow of the rest of the page under it (divs hiding beneath it). I tried using a ghost div at a matching height to correct for the height of the area which was out of flow, but when it gets scaled down to the mobile sizes, it doesn't work with my responsive styling due to variable heights (where text determines height).

I'd like to find an alternative that doesn't require absolute positioning, if possible, as it will allow me to keep the rest of my work as-is and keep the responsive features working. Plus I'm just not a fan of absolute positioning unless absolutely necessary. ;)

Presently, I'm using absolute positioning and overflow:hidden; to line up the 4 div "sliders" next to each other.. using left:100%;, left:200%;, etc.

I'd like to find a way to line up the 4 divs (100% width each, totalling 400% width) side-by-side, with overflow hidden, so that my slider will still function the same, but without using absolute positioning. Preferably using only CSS.

Here are the relevant portions of CSS, and the HTML (not sure if it's all relevant):

```css
/* SLIDER CONTAINER */

.css-slider-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* SLIDERS */

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 68px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms, transform 1600ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.slide-1 {
  left: 0;
}

.slide-2 {
  left: 100%
}

.slide-3 {
  left: 200%
}

.slide-4 {
  left: 300%;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slider-wrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" checked id="slider_1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" id="slider_2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio4" id="slider_4">


  <!-- Slider #1 -->
  <div class="slider slide-1">CONTENT</div>

  <!-- Slider #2 -->
  <div class="slider slide-2">CONTENT</div>

  <!-- Slider #3 -->
  <div class="slider slide-3">CONTENT</div>

  <!-- Slider #4 -->
  <div class="slider slide-4">CONTENT</div>

  <!-- Slider Pagination -->
  <div class="slider-pagination">
    <label for="slider_1" class="page1"></label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="page2"></label>
    <label for="slider_3" class="page3"></label>
    <label for="slider_4" class="page4"></label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the sliders with a flexbox (`.sliders-container`), and set the flex of each slider to `flex: 0 0 100vw;` (don't grow, don't shrink, base size screen width.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

/* SLIDER CONTAINER */

.css-slider-wrapper {
  /** overflow: hidden; **/
}

.sliders-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 90vh;
}

/* SLIDERS */

.slider {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 100vw;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms;
  transition: -webkit-transform 1600ms, transform 1600ms;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.slide-1 {
  background: red;
}

.slide-2 {
  background: blue;
}

.slide-3 {
  background: green;
}

.slide-4 {
  background: yellow;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-slider-wrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio1" checked id="slider_1">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio2" id="slider_2">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio3" id="slider_3">
  <input type="radio" name="slider" class="slide-radio4" id="slider_4">

  <div class="sliders-container">
    <!-- Slider #1 -->
    <div class="slider slide-1">CONTENT</div>

    <!-- Slider #2 -->
    <div class="slider slide-2">CONTENT</div>

    <!-- Slider #3 -->
    <div class="slider slide-3">CONTENT</div>

    <!-- Slider #4 -->
    <div class="slider slide-4">CONTENT</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Slider Pagination -->
  <div class="slider-pagination">
    <label for="slider_1" class="page1"></label>
    <label for="slider_2" class="page2"></label>
    <label for="slider_3" class="page3"></label>
    <label for="slider_4" class="page4"></label>
  </div>

</div>
```